# RegEx in Notepad++ To Remove or Replace Range of Text

Tags: regex, search, replace, find, notepad++

I just go through the **RegEx** answers to the questions by other mates but couldn't find any solution for the problem in my case.
I also read the Regular Expressions references given by some of the helpers here but I was not able to understand properly.

I am editing my sitemaps of websites. In the sitemap, I have some links in the form:

```
http://foo.com/download/something-after-download-different-for-each-link-12-23-2014.html?id=my5sIUosfiQ&amp;itag=18
```

And I want to change all those links to simply:

```
http://foo.com/download/?id=my5sIUosfiQ&amp;itag=18
```

Here, `?id=` and `itag=` values are different for each link. So, these should not get changed for each link which are already mentioned.

Plus, the part `something-after-download-different-for-each-link-12-23-2014.html` is also different for each link as every file is different to download. So, I want to basically remove the this part from each link. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've reformatted your question to make it more readable (I hope I didn't break anything). When you've got the time, check out the help section for the editor, it has some nifty features, especially for code formatting. Now, to your question - one before/after example might not be enough for us to guess the rule involved. Is it simply "remove everything after `/download/` until the first `?` character"?

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'll try to format even better next time. Secondly: Yes, I want to remove everything after /download/PART-TO-REMOVE? or until the first ? as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that might work -
(*Note that the odds of finding an errant `/download/` not followed

by non-whitespace nor question mark, then a question mark,

make this virtually impossible to match anything other than the url's*)

If np++ uses the `\K` construct you could use this
Find: `/download/\K[^\s?]+(?=\?)`
Replace: nothing

If it doesn't, you could use this
Find: `(?<=/download/)[^\s?]+(?=\?)`
Replace: nothing

or, even better
Find: `(/download/)[^\s?]+(?=\?)`
Replace: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

You should find

```
http://foo\.com/download/[^?]*\?id=(.*)
```

and replace it with

```
http://foo\.com/download/\?$1
```

This grabs everything between `...download/` and `?id=...` and removes it.

Comment: This didn't work. Result was 0 Occurrence replaced. I tried from the above answer then and it worked.

Comment: "This didn't work" isn't particularly helpful. Since it *does* work on your test string, please consider writing a more specific question next time around....

Answer (score 0):

Enable regex and use this search & replace:

Find:

```
(http://foo.com/download/)(.*)(\?id=my5sIUosfiQ&amp;itag=18)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\3
```